# Hosting XSB Prolog in a Server

Tags: web-applications, server, prolog, xsb

I wanted to host XSB Prolog in a server. Can someone please tell me what the procedure is?
The following git link explains how to host SWIPL on a server, but the same is not working for XSB
https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swish

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to host **XSB** on server, just use subprocesses to be spawned to **XSB**.

see the [XSB Manual](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/shadow_site/manual2/manual2.pdf)

`spawn_process(+CmdSpec,-StreamToProc,-StreamFromProc,-ProcStderrStream,ProcId)`

*Spawn a new process specified by* **CmdSpec**

One of the uses of **XSB** subprocesses is to create **XSB** servers that spawn subprocesses and
control them. 
A spawned subprocess can be another **XSB** process. 
The following example shows one **XSB** process spawning another, sending it a goal to evaluate and obtaining the result:

```
`| ?-` spawn_process([xsb], To, From,Err,_),
     file_write(To,’assert(p(1)).’),
     file_nl(To),
     file_flush(To,_),
     file_write(To,’p(X), writeln(X).’),
     file_nl(To),
     file_flush(To,_),
     file_read_line_atom(From,XX).

`XX = 126`
`yes`
`| ?-`
"Here the parent **XSB** process sends “
`assert(p(1)).`
” and then “
`p(X), writeln(X).`
” to the spawned XSB subprocess."
"The latter evaluates the goal and prints (via “ `writeln(X)` ”) 
to its standard output..."
```

Comment: is this like pengines?